# centered "row" content with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem to center the content in a "row", the buttons in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sTwj7/) are always on the left side and i have too much space on the right side.

Is there a way to center this buttons?

thx
tomas

```
<div class="abc">
<div class="row red show-grid">
    <div class="span2 btn">a</div>
    <div class="span2 btn">b</div>
    <div class="span2 btn">c</div>
    <div class="span2 btn">d</div>
    <div class="span2 btn">e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove/overwrite the `float:left`, and set `text-align:center` for the parent element. Btw., this is terrible HTML – I hope it’s just a bad example and not your real code(?)

Answer (score 0):

The class `span2` has property `float:left`:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="row show-grid">
        <div class="span2 btn">a</div>
        <div class="span2 btn">b</div>
        <div class="span2 btn">c</div>
        <div class="span2 btn">d</div>
        <div class="span2 btn">e</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    max-width: 500px;
}
.block > div {
    text-align:center;
}
.block > div > div {
    float:none; 
}
```

I would consider not using `span2` (layout and grid class) with `btn` (button style class) together.

Comment: If i remove the "btn" because it was only for the example, it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/sTwj7/2/

Answer (score 0):

***Updated 2018***

**Bootstrap 4**

Use the auto-layout columns and `text-center`

```
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm border">a</div>
    <div class="col-sm border">b</div>
    <div class="col-sm border">c</div>
    <div class="col-sm border">d</div>
    <div class="col-sm border">e</div>
  </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/2fDFPSB5A4

---

**Bootstrap 3**

Use column offset and `text-center`

```
  <div class="row red show-grid text-center">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 btn btn-default">a</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 btn btn-default">b</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 btn btn-default">c</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 btn btn-default">d</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 btn btn-default">e</div>
  </div>
```

https://www.bootply.com/zEYom4EJUF

---

**Bootstrap 2** (original answer)

You could add CSS to center your spans like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sTwj7/9/

```
<div class="span2 pull-center">
     <h1>a</h1>
</div>
```

CSS class:

```
.pull-center {text-align:center;margin:0 auto !important;float:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sTwj7/10/

HTML

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="row red show-grid">
        <div class="btn">a</div>
        <div class="btn">b</div>
        <div class="btn">c</div>
        <div class="btn">d</div>
        <div class="btn">e</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.abc {
    max-width: 500px;
}

.red .btn {
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```